# Trouble Declaring Vertex u within DFS

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been trying to solve this depthFirstSearch Algorithm and while I have followed the pseudocode properly, I've been having severe trouble trying to declare a vertex within the algorithm.

Here's the Algorithm:

```
    public GraphAdjacencyList depthFirstSearch(Vertex start) {
        Stack<Vertex>S = new Stack<Vertex>();
        ArrayList<Vertex>visited = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        HashMap<Vertex,Vertex>predecessor = new HashMap<Vertex,Vertex>();
        for(int i = 0;i<listOfVertices.size();i++) {
            listOfVertices.get(i).setVisited(false);
        }
        S.push(start);
        while(S.size()>0); {
            Vertex u = S.pop();
            if(!u.getVisited())
                u.setVisited(true);
                visited.add(u);
                for(Vertex w: getAdjacentVertices(u)) {
                    if(!w.getVisited())
                        S.push(w);
                        predecessor.put(w,u);
                }
        }
        **GraphAdjacencyList T = new GraphAdjacencyList(listOfVertices);
        for(Vertex v:visited) {
            Vertex u = null;
            if(predecessor.containsKey(v)) 
                u = predecessor.get(v);
                T.addDirectedEdge(u,v,1);
        }
        return T;**
    }
```

And here's the Driver/testing code to check if it works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class GraphSearchingAndDijkstraDriverAndGrader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        
        Vertex A = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex B = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex C = new Vertex("C");
        Vertex D = new Vertex("D");
        vertices.add(A);
        vertices.add(B);
        vertices.add(C);
        vertices.add(D);
        
        //Create graph1 for testing
        GraphAdjacencyList graph1 = new GraphAdjacencyList(vertices);           
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(A, B, 1);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(A, C, 3);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(B, C, 1);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(C, D, 2);
        
        int points = 0;
        
        points+=5; //constructed graph1
        //Output graph1 to match provided formatting
        System.out.println("Graph for testing:\n\n"+graph1); //test toString
        ArrayList<Vertex> adjacentToA = graph1.getAdjacentVertices(A);
        if(adjacentToA != null && adjacentToA.size() ==2)
            points+=5; //toString print of graph1
        else
            System.out.println("Either failed to add edges to A. Fix Add UndirectedEdge. Or, getAdjacentVertices is not correctly implemented.");
        
        System.out.println("You have "+points+" initial points from creating and printing graph1"); 
        System.out.println("Earned "+points+" of 10 points");

//*************Test the implementation**************************************
                
//breadthFirstSearch testing

    
        GraphAdjacencyList bfs = graph1.breadthFirstSearch(A);
        System.out.println("breadthFirstSearch(A) results: \n" + bfs); //test toString      
        ArrayList<Vertex> bfsAdjacentA, bfsTestA;
        bfsTestA = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        bfsTestA.add(B); bfsTestA.add(C);
        bfsAdjacentA = bfs.getAdjacentVertices(A);
        
        if(bfsAdjacentA != null && bfsAdjacentA.containsAll(bfsTestA)&& !bfsAdjacentA.contains(D))
            points+=4;
        else
            System.out.println("breadthFirstSearch failed to reach both B and C");
        
        
        if(bfs.getAdjacentVertices(B) != null && bfs.getAdjacentVertices(B).size() ==0 )// && adjacentD.contains(C))
            points+=3;
        else
            System.out.println("BFS Adjacent B should not have any adjacent vertices");
        
        
        if(bfs.getAdjacentVertices(C) != null && bfs.getAdjacentVertices(C).size() == 1 && bfs.getAdjacentVertices(C).contains(D))// && adjacentD.contains(C))
            points+=3;
        else
            System.out.println("BFS Adjacent C should have one adjacent vertice D");
    
        System.out.println("Earned "+points+" of 20 total points past breadthFirstSearch testing");

     
        
//test depthFirstSearch on new clean graph1 
        
    
        graph1 = new GraphAdjacencyList(vertices);          
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(A, B, 1);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(A, C, 3);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(B, C, 1);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(C, D, 2);
        
        GraphAdjacencyList dfs = graph1.depthFirstSearch(A);
        System.out.println("depthFirstSearch(A) results: \n" + dfs); //test toString        
        ArrayList<Vertex> dfsAdjacentA;
        
        dfsAdjacentA = dfs.getAdjacentVertices(A);
        
        if(dfsAdjacentA != null && (dfsAdjacentA.contains(B)||dfsAdjacentA.contains(C) ) && !dfsAdjacentA.contains(D))
            points+=6;
        else
            System.out.println("depthFirstSearch should reach either B or C but not both");
        
        
        if(dfs.getAdjacentVertices(D) != null && dfs.getAdjacentVertices(D).size() ==0 )
            points+=4;
        else
            System.out.println("DFS Adjacent D should not have any adjacent vertices");
        
            
        System.out.println("Earned "+points+" of 30 points past depthFirstSearch");
    
        
//test BFS and DFS on larger graph2
    
    
        //Second Graph to test
        ArrayList<Vertex> vertices2 = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        
        Vertex a = new Vertex("a");
        Vertex b = new Vertex("b");
        Vertex c = new Vertex("c");
        Vertex d = new Vertex("d");
        Vertex e = new Vertex("e");
        Vertex f = new Vertex("f");
                
        vertices2.add(a);
        vertices2.add(b);
        vertices2.add(c);
        vertices2.add(d);
        vertices2.add(e);
        vertices2.add(f);
        
        
        GraphAdjacencyList graph2 = new GraphAdjacencyList(vertices2);
                
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(a, c, 1);
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(a, d, 1);
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(c, e, 1 );
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(c, b, 1);
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(d, e, 1);
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(e, f, 1);
        graph2.addUndirectedEdge(b, f, 1);
        
        System.out.println("Graph2:\n"+graph2);
        
        GraphAdjacencyList bfs2 = graph2.breadthFirstSearch(a);
        if(bfs2.getAdjacentVertices(a) != null && bfs2.getAdjacentVertices(a).size() ==2 )
            points+=2;
        else
            System.out.println("BFS Adjacent a should have two adjacent vertices");
        
        GraphAdjacencyList dfsTree2 = graph2.depthFirstSearch(a);
        if(dfsTree2.getAdjacentVertices(a) != null && dfsTree2.getAdjacentVertices(a).size() ==1 )
            points+=2;
        else
            System.out.println("DFS Adjacent a should have one adjacent vertices");
        
        //BFS and DFS from Vertex c
        GraphAdjacencyList bfsTree2c = graph2.breadthFirstSearch(c);
        if(bfsTree2c.getAdjacentVertices(c) != null && bfsTree2c.getAdjacentVertices(c).size() ==3 )
            points+=3;
        else
            System.out.println("BFS Adjacent c should have three adjacent vertices");
        
        GraphAdjacencyList dfsTree2c = graph2.depthFirstSearch(c);
        if(dfsTree2c.getAdjacentVertices(c) != null && dfsTree2c.getAdjacentVertices(c).size() ==1 )
            points+=3;
        else
            System.out.println("DFS Adjacent c should have one adjacent vertex");

        System.out.println("Earned "+points+" of 40 total points past second graph with bfs and dfs\n\n");
    
        
//test Dijkstras in ArrayList on new clean graph1   
        
    /*
        System.out.println("Starting testing of Dijkstra's Algorithm:");
        graph1 = new GraphAdjacencyList(vertices);          
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(A, B, 1);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(A, C, 3);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(B, C, 1);
        graph1.addUndirectedEdge(C, D, 2);
        
        graph1.Dijkstra(A);
        
        if(A.getDistance() == 0 )
            points+=2;
        else
            System.out.println("Distance should be 0 in start Vertex A");
        
        if(B.getDistance() == 1 )
            points+=2;
        else
            System.out.println("Distance should be 1 in Vertex B");
        
        if(C.getDistance() == 2 )
            points+=3;
        else
            System.out.println("Distance should be 2 in Vertex C (not 3)");
        
        if(D.getDistance() == 4 )
            points+=3;
        else
            System.out.println("Distance should be 4 in Vertex D");
        
        System.out.println("Earned "+points+" of 50 total points past Dijkstras");
        
     */

        System.out.println("\nFinal points: "+points+" of 50 total points ");
        
    }
}
```

I already completed the BreadthFirstSearch algorithm and the Dijkstra's algorithm, I just need to figure out the problem I've been having with DepthFirstSearch.

I believe the problem lies in trying to declare Vertex u within the last for loop, but I have tried many ways to declare it and the output still displays nothing for the algorithm. (The double asterisk line within the DFS algorithm)

I have already completed the standard Vertex code, the Graphable interface, and the CompareByDistance. All I want to know is how do I declare u within the DFS algorithm?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what the actual problem is. Can you give us a precise and concise description of the problem? Like: What is the input, what is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: Your first while-loop is an infinite loop: `while(S.size()>0); {` the semicolon ends the loop-body, so you'll forever repeat an empty loop. Remove it: `while(S.size()>0) {`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quire sure what you're asking. Please state a clear example of expected and observed behavior with the relevant input.

But I can see a few possible errors in your code:

- You have an empty while-loop here:

  ```
    while(S.size() > 0); {
  ```

  Get rid of the ';'

  ```
    while(S.size() > 0) {
  ```
- None of your if statements use brackets, so the then-part will only be the next line:

  ```
    while( S.size() > 0 )
    {
        Vertex u = S.pop();
        if(!u.getVisited())
            u.setVisited(true);
        visited.add(u);
        for(Vertex w: getAdjacentVertices(u)) {
            if(!w.getVisited())
                S.push(w);
            predecessor.put(w,u);
        }
    }
    GraphAdjacencyList T = new GraphAdjacencyList(listOfVertices);
    for(Vertex v : visited) {
        Vertex u = null;
        if(predecessor.containsKey(v)) 
            u = predecessor.get(v);
        T.addDirectedEdge(u,v,1);
    }
    return T;
  ```

  }

  Is that what you want? Or should it be this:

  ```
    while( S.size() > 0 ) {
        Vertex u = S.pop();
        if( !u.getVisited() ) {                   // <-----
            u.setVisited(true);
            visited.add(u);
            for( Vertex w : getAdjacentVertices(u) ) {
                if( !w.getVisited() ) {           // <-----
                    S.push(w);
                    predecessor.put(w, u);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    GraphAdjacencyList T = new GraphAdjacencyList(listOfVertices);
    for( Vertex v : visited ) {
        Vertex u = null;
        if( predecessor.containsKey(v) ) {        // <-----
            u = predecessor.get(v);
            T.addDirectedEdge(u, v, 1);
        }
    }
    return T;
  ```